# HTTP Post request with custom header

Tags: c#, http-headers

I want to make a HTTP Post request from C#. This request has a custom headers. When I try to start my program I received this exception:

Italian:

> Questa intestazione deve essere modificata utilizzando la proprietà o
>   il metodo appropriato. Nome parametro: name

English:

> This header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.

On line: `request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8");`

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Web;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.androidlost.com/androidlost/greet");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8");
            string postData = "Test";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use WebRequest.ContentType property. Some headers can be set using API properties only.

EDIT:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.androidlost.com/androidlost/greet");
request.ContentType = "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: thanks andy... please write me a snippet of code to resolve the problem... regards

Answer (score 3):

According to the MSDN documentation, [HttpWebRequest.Header Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers.aspx).

The Content-Type are modified using the `ContentType` property.
This requires that you cast the `WebRequest`to `HttpWebRequest`

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.androidlost.com/androidlost/greet");
```